# Button's don't want to be the right size

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have social media buttons for my portfolio website, and they won't be the right size after changing the way I display the icons (from background to image tags).

Here are the social media buttons (image tags, wrong size):
[image: Social media buttons, image tags and wrong size]

And here are the buttons a bit below (background images, right size):
[image: Buttons below, background images and right size]

Note that the images are the same size in both screenshots, the only thing bigger are the buttons.

Now here is the html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title id="ltitle">Cocolennon's Dev Stuff</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png">
        <meta name="description" content="I'm a 15 year old software and web developer from France.">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'> 
        <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'> 
        <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
        <meta content="#A020F0" data-react-helmet="true" name="theme-color">
        <meta content="https://www.cocolennon.xyz/favicon.png" property="og:image" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="header">
            <a href="#" class="logo">Cocolennon</a>
            <nav class="navbar">
                <a href="#about-me">About Me</a>
                <!--
                <a href="#">Projects</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
                -->
                <a href="#" onclick="setLang('en')">English</a>
                <a href="#" onclick="setLang('fr')">Français</a>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <h1 class="name">
            <span id="lname">Sup, my name's </span>
            <span style="color:darkorchid" id="lcoco">Cocolennon</span>
            <span class="aka" id="laka"> aka Coco</span>
        </h1>
        <h1 class="desc">
            <span id="lshort">I'm a 15 year old software and web developer from </span>
            <span style="color:blue" id="lfr">Fr</span><span id="lan">an</span><span style="color:red" id="lce">ce</span>.
        </h1>
        <div class="hsocials">
            <div class="socials">
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/@cocolennon_" target="_blank" draggable="false">
                    <button class="button">
                        <img class="button-icon" draggable="false" alt="YouTube" src="images/svgs/socials/youtube.svg">
                    </button>
                </a>
                <a href="https://discord.gg/yqG4u2JnrV" target="_blank" draggable="false">
                    <button class="button">
                        <img class="button-icon" draggable="false" alt="Discord" src="images/svgs/socials/discord.svg">
                    </button>
                </a>
                <a href="https://github.com/Cocolennon" target="_blank" draggable="false">
                    <button class="button">
                        <img class="button-icon" draggable="false" alt="GitHub" src="images/svgs/socials/github.svg">
                    </button>
                </a>
                <a href="https://paypal.me/Cocolennon" target="_blank" draggable="false">
                    <button class="button">
                        <img class="button-icon" draggable="false" alt="PayPal" src="images/svgs/socials/paypal.svg">
                    </button>
                </a>
                <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/Cocolennon/" target="_blank" draggable="false">
                    <button class="button">
                        <img class="button-icon" draggable="false" alt="Steam" src="images/svgs/socials/steam.svg">
                    </button>
                </a>
                <a href="https://namemc.com/profile/CCocolennon.1" target="_blank" draggable="false">
                    <button class="button">
                        <img class="button-icon" draggable="false" alt="NameMC" src="images/svgs/socials/namemc.svg">
                    </button>
                </a>
                <a href="https://e-z.bio/cocolennon" target="_blank" draggable="false">
                    <button class="button">
                        <img class="button-icon" draggable="false" alt="E-Z Bio" src="images/svgs/socials/ezhost.svg">
                    </button>
                </a>
                <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/cocolennon_" target="_blank" draggable="false">
                    <button class="button">
                        <img class="button-icon" draggable="false" alt="Twitch" src="images/svgs/socials/twitch.svg">
                    </button>
                </a>
                <a href="mailto:contact@cocolennon.xyz" target="_blank" draggable="false">
                    <button class="button">
                        <img class="button-icon" draggable="false" alt="GMail" src="images/svgs/socials/gmail.svg">
                    </button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="about">    
            <h1 id="about-me">A bit more about me.</h1>
            <h2 id="devlang">I'm learning a lot of languages, libraries and frameworks.</h2>
            <div class="hlang">
                <nav class="dlang">
                    <a href="java" target="_blank" draggable="false">
                        <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/dev/lang/java.svg);"></button>
                    </a>
                    <a href="csharp" target="_blank" draggable="false">
                        <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/dev/lang/csharp.svg);"></button>
                    </a>
                    <a href="lua" target="_blank" draggable="false">
                        <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/dev/lang/lua.svg);"></button>
                    </a>
                    <a href="javascript" target="_blank" draggable="false">
                        <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/dev/lang/javascript.svg);"></button>
                    </a>
                    <a href="html" target="_blank" draggable="false">
                        <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/dev/lang/html.svg);"></button>
                    </a>
                    <a href="css" target="_blank" draggable="false">
                        <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/dev/lang/css.svg);"></button>
                    </a>
                    <a href="typescript" target="_blank" draggable="false">
                        <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/dev/lang/typescript.svg);"></button>
                    </a>
                    <a href="nodejs" target="_blank" draggable="false">
                        <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/dev/lang/nodejs.svg);"></button>
                    </a>
                    <a href="discordjs" target="_blank" draggable="false">
                        <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/dev/lang/discordjs.svg);"></button>
                    </a>
                    <a href="mysql" target="_blank" draggable="false">
                        <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/dev/lang/mysql.svg);"></button>
                    </a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the css:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit:wght@500&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

html {
    min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(36,37,34,0.9),rgba(36,37,34,0.9)), url('images/grid.png');
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 100px;
    background:#46354e;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 100;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.navbar a {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 3vw;
    transition: .3s;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    color: darkorchid;
}

.navbar a::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    transition: .3s;
}

.navbar a:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: darkorchid;
}

.name {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 10%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 44px;
}

.aka {
    color: rgb(94, 94, 94);
    font-size: 22px;
    font-style: italic;
}

.desc {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 44px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    top: 45%;
}

.hsocials {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 9.2%;
}

.socials a {
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition: .3s;
}

.button {
    background-color: #525050;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: 60%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: center;
    background-position-y: center;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.button-icon {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #949191;
    border-radius: 30%;
}

#about-me {
    position: absolute;
    top: 110%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 44px;
}

#devlang {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

.hlang {
    position: absolute;
    top: 130%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.dlang a {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition: .3s;
}
```

I have tried using padding to center and resize the images automatically but it didn't work.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might want to avoid putting personal information, especially your age, in your posts online.

Comment: You don't need to use `<a><button>`, just `<a>` alone will do.

Comment: I managed to get them to be the right size using flexbox and by reorganizing the buttons a little, but now they're in rows instead of columns (even when using `flex-direction: column`).
I have also removed the `<button>` tags and made it only `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question.

So, first, I removed a layer of divs so I only had `<div> <a>` instead of `<div> <div> <a>`
Then I made my buttons display in `inline-flex` and they all sized properly and as a beautiful row of buttons.

Here is the html and css for those who think they might find an answer to their problem in this post:

```html
    <div class="scs">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/@cocolennon_" target="_blank" draggable="false" class="btnn">
                <img class="button-icon" draggable="false" alt="YouTube" src="images/svgs/socials/youtube.svg">
            </a>
            <a href="https://discord.gg/yqG4u2JnrV" target="_blank" draggable="false" class="btnn">
                <img class="button-icon" draggable="false" alt="Discord" src="images/svgs/socials/discord.svg">
            </a>
            <a href="https://github.com/Cocolennon" target="_blank" draggable="false" class="btnn">
                <img class="button-icon" draggable="false" alt="GitHub" src="images/svgs/socials/github.svg">
            </a>
            <a href="https://paypal.me/Cocolennon" target="_blank" draggable="false" class="btnn">
                <img class="button-icon" draggable="false" alt="PayPal" src="images/svgs/socials/paypal.svg">
            </a>
            <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/Cocolennon/" target="_blank" draggable="false" class="btnn">
                <img class="button-icon" draggable="false" alt="Steam" src="images/svgs/socials/steam.svg">
            </a>
            <a href="https://namemc.com/profile/CCocolennon.1" target="_blank" draggable="false" class="btnn">
                <img class="button-icon" draggable="false" alt="NameMC" src="images/svgs/socials/namemc.svg">
            </a>
            <a href="https://e-z.bio/cocolennon" target="_blank" draggable="false" class="btnn">
                <img class="button-icon" draggable="false" alt="E-Z Bio" src="images/svgs/socials/ezhost.svg">
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/cocolennon_" target="_blank" draggable="false" class="btnn">
                <img class="button-icon" draggable="false" alt="Twitch" src="images/svgs/socials/twitch.svg">
            </a>
            <a href="mailto:contact@cocolennon.xyz" target="_blank" draggable="false" class="btnn">
                <img class="button-icon" draggable="false" alt="GMail" src="images/svgs/socials/gmail.svg">
            </a>
    </div>
```

```css
.scs {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65%;
    left: 9.2%;
}

.btnn {
    background-color: #525050;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.button-icon {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
}
```